# How to disable the style hint in css Vs code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plRph.png)
How to disable the style hint in css Vs code?

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint

stylelint.enable=false
In your Setting.json File